# Flutter animation sliver

Tags: flutter, animation

I'm a flutter developer. I want to build my Appbar with some fancy animation like the below gif.
I think maybe this "Appbar" must be SliverPersistentHeader and AnimatedPosition. But I don't know how to do it.

[image]

Comment: Yes, it is using `SliverAppBar` can you include the code-snippet that you have tried so far?

Comment: yes indeed, for complex cases you need `SliverPersistentHeader` - check `SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate.build` method documentation and based on `double shrinkOffset` parameter you need to build your layout

Comment: Thank you for your help. Would you advise me on how to build my layout? I think all of these items(upper and lower icons, search bar,) must be children of a Stack. But it would be a headache if I place it without Row or  Column.

Comment: use `CustomMultiChildLayout`, not `Stack`

Answer (score 0):

Please try this below example code of similar kind

```
class AnimatedAppBar extends StatefulWidget {
  const AnimatedAppBar({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AnimatedAppBarState createState() => _AnimatedAppBarState();
}

class _AnimatedAppBarState extends State<AnimatedAppBar> {
  final TextEditingController stateController = TextEditingController();
  final FocusNode stateFocus = FocusNode();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: NestedScrollView(
          headerSliverBuilder:
              (BuildContext context, bool innnerBoxIsScrolled) {
            return <Widget>[
              SliverAppBar(
                expandedHeight: 150.0,
                floating: false,
                pinned: true,
                backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
                titleSpacing: 0.0,
                centerTitle: false,
                elevation: 0.0,
                leadingWidth: 0.0,
                title: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    if (innnerBoxIsScrolled != null &&
                        innnerBoxIsScrolled == true)
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          horizontal: 10.0,
                        ),
                        child: Row(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: [
                            Icon(
                              Icons.note,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                            Icon(
                              Icons.note,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                            Icon(
                              Icons.note,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                            Icon(
                              Icons.note,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                            Icon(
                              Icons.fullscreen,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                            Icon(
                              Icons.search,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                            Icon(
                              Icons.notifications,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                  ],
                ),
                flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                  background: Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    child: Stack(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 10.0,
                            ),
                            Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: [
                                SizedBox(
                                  width: 10.0,
                                ),
                                /* State */
                                Expanded(
                                  child: TextFormField(
                                    autovalidateMode:
                                        AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                                    /* autovalidate is disabled */
                                    controller: stateController,
                                    inputFormatters: [
                                      FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(
                                          RegExp(r"\s\s")),
                                      FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(RegExp(
                                          r'(\u00a9|\u00ae|[\u2000-\u3300]|\ud83c[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83d[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83e[\ud000-\udfff])')),
                                    ],
                                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                                    maxLength: 160,
                                    onChanged: (val) {},
                                    maxLines: 1,
                                    validator: (value) {},
                                    focusNode: stateFocus,
                                    autofocus: false,
                                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                                      errorMaxLines: 3,
                                      counterText: "",
                                      filled: true,
                                      fillColor: Colors.white,
                                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                            Radius.circular(4)),
                                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                                          width: 1,
                                          color: Color(0xffE5E5E5),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      disabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                            Radius.circular(4)),
                                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                                          width: 1,
                                          color: Color(0xffE5E5E5),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                            Radius.circular(4)),
                                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                                          width: 1,
                                          color: Color(0xffE5E5E5),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                            Radius.circular(4)),
                                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                                          width: 1,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                              Radius.circular(4)),
                                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                                            width: 1,
                                            color: Colors.red,
                                          )),
                                      focusedErrorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                            Radius.circular(4)),
                                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                                          width: 1,
                                          color: Colors.red,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      hintText: "Enter state" ?? "",
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 15.0,
                                ),
                                if (innnerBoxIsScrolled != null &&
                                    innnerBoxIsScrolled == true)
                                  Text(
                                    "Name" ?? "",
                                    maxLines: 2,
                                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                IconButton(
                                  icon: Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                                    child: Icon(
                                      Icons.notifications,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      size: 18,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  onPressed: () {},
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 10.0,
                            ),
                            Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                Row(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  mainAxisAlignment:
                                      MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                  children: [
                                    Container(
                                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width *
                                          0.20,
                                      child: Column(
                                        crossAxisAlignment:
                                            CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                        mainAxisAlignment:
                                            MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                        children: [
                                          Container(
                                            width: 50.0,
                                            height: 50.0,
                                            child: Icon(
                                              Icons.note,
                                              color: Colors.white,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          SizedBox(
                                            height: 2.0,
                                          ),
                                          Text(
                                            "Attach Docs",
                                            maxLines: 6,
                                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      width: 5.0,
                                    ),
                                    Container(
                                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width *
                                          0.20,
                                      child: Column(
                                        crossAxisAlignment:
                                            CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                        mainAxisAlignment:
                                            MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                        children: [
                                          Container(
                                            width: 50.0,
                                            height: 50.0,
                                            child: Icon(
                                              Icons.note,
                                              color: Colors.white,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          SizedBox(
                                            height: 2.0,
                                          ),
                                          Text(
                                            "Attach Docs",
                                            maxLines: 6,
                                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      width: 5.0,
                                    ),
                                    Container(
                                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width *
                                          0.20,
                                      child: Column(
                                        crossAxisAlignment:
                                            CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                        mainAxisAlignment:
                                            MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                        children: [
                                          Container(
                                            width: 50.0,
                                            height: 50.0,
                                            child: Icon(
                                              Icons.note,
                                              color: Colors.white,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          SizedBox(
                                            height: 2.0,
                                          ),
                                          Text(
                                            "Attach Docs",
                                            maxLines: 6,
                                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      width: 5.0,
                                    ),
                                    Container(
                                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width *
                                          0.20,
                                      child: Column(
                                        crossAxisAlignment:
                                            CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                        mainAxisAlignment:
                                            MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                        children: [
                                          Container(
                                            width: 50.0,
                                            height: 50.0,
                                            child: Icon(
                                              Icons.note,
                                              color: Colors.white,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          SizedBox(
                                            height: 2.0,
                                          ),
                                          Text(
                                            "Attach Docs",
                                            maxLines: 6,
                                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ];
          },
          body: Builder(
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: 100,
                      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                          child: Text("Index value: $index"),
                        );
                      },
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```